# Laravel documentation for testing?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

Is there a thorough documentation for different commands for writing phpunit tests with Laravel?

All I can find are introduction-level docs like https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/application-testing, but nothing that would give more info about the available methods and their parameters.

Also, I haven't found a way to extend the test files beyond the default

```
php artisan make:test SomeTest
```

At least I would like to change the `testExample()` function name to something more describing and add several functions in the test file.

Comment: You might find Laravel's [API documentation for `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing.html) helpful.

Comment: A laravel testcase extends a PHPUnit test case and has some additional assertions documented at https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/application-testing#phpunit-assertions